# Don't find the right file

Tags: asp.net, image

I try to work with Image but I got this fold and I don't no why.
The picture is in the root of the project.
I tried also this:
.FromFile("~/aPicture.jpg");
.FromFile("../aPicture.jpg");

[image]

anyone a idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current directory of iis is the dir in which iis is running. You should use Server.MapPath to map your ~/aPicture.jpg to the directory of your site:

```
.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/aPicture.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Server.MapPath ( "~/aPicture.Jpg"); should give you correct path for file.
```

Answer (score 0):

`/` will take you back to the base folder of your project